# Set column to full height of the page

Tags: css, height

I'm attempting to create a column in css that is 100% height of the page. Specificially the left column with the background transparency.

I've tried to make the contain use the overflow: hidden,  but it doesn't seem to be working.  I know I'm targeting the issue incorrectly and and I think that the header and footer are messing the columns up.

Comment: in this article you can find the answer and the reason of why your code does not work :
http://apptools.com/examples/tableheight.php

Comment: You should explain the problem rather than linking to a page of text

Comment: thanks for this link Afshin, I can't seem to find the solution though in the article.  If you have something obvious to you that I'm not able to understand I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Gabe that's why I added a comment instead of answering,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the height with javascript ( using jQuery in this case) at page load :

```
$(function () {

 $('.left_col').height($(document).height());

});
```

and just in case the user resizes the window :

```
$(window).resize( function () {

 $('.left_col').height($(document).height());

});
```

Comment: I tried this, but can't get it to work. Instead of '.left_col'  I'm using:  '.col8 .mainframe'

Comment: Actually I think I got it.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

For this idea you want to apply the [Faux Column](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique. This is how a 100% sidebar is done. You have a repeating image that extends to the bottom of the page, making it appear as it is an actual sidebar.